# Missing JFrame? Or just in full screen?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I've got an issue with a `JFrame` (my guess). It looks pretty weird though:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/bc7rrc95rw5uvi1/jFrameBug.PNG

Can you help me make the frame? Bug look like this one:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/x3f2sb74llii1s7/jFrameOK.PNG

Comment: You can paste your code here.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  Note the document is being reviewed and discussed on [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214955/155831), contributions welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are calling `frame.setUndecorated(true);` somewhere in your code. If you remove that line, it should get back its title bar and border.

Comment: Does invoking Undecorated(true); remove the title bar and border? What are the other frame properties that come under decoration of frame?

Comment: The API mentions about frame "decorations", it doesn't explain which they are.

Comment: Yeah,I read it as well.Let me take at this point that setUndecorated(true); removes title bar and border.